# Convert a sql query using sqlglot replace method

Tags: python, sqlglot

I want to achieve the following sql query conversion using sqlglot

`select * from table where date > abc.def(2 * days)` to

`select * from table where date > {@abc.def(2 * days).xyz(yyyy)}`

For the first conversion i.e `abc` to `{@abc}`, I used the following replacement and it worked:

```
tree = sqlglot.parse_one(query)
tree.find(sqlglot.exp.Var).replace(sqlglot.exp.Var(this="{@abc"))
```

Can somebody help with the next conversion i.e `def(2 * days)` to `def(2 * days).xyz(yyy)}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from sqlglot import parse_one, exp

expr = parse_one("select * from table where date > abc.def(2 * days)")

dot = expr.find(exp.Dot)

dot.replace(exp.Dot.build([dot.copy(), exp.func("xyz", "yyyy")]))

print(expr.sql())
```

Results in:

```
'SELECT * FROM table WHERE date > abc.DEF(2 * days).XYZ(yyyy)'
```

Comment: Thanks. I also solved it using replace method by identifying the dot operators. btw good work with sqlglot _/\_